# DataBase Error when running python manage.py runserver

Tags: database, django

I am working with Django 1.4.3 on PowerShell and I am getting a DataBase error after running `python manage.py` with 
the Exception Value:

`(1054, "Unknown column 'ventas_cliente.apellidos' in 'field list'")`

So I am following a Django tutorial and I have the following directory for a project:

```
demo/
    demo/
        apps/
            ventas/
                __init__.py
                admin.py
                models.py
                tests.py
                views.py
            __init.py
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
 manage
```

And under admin.py I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from demo.apps.ventas.models import cliente.producto

# Register the ventas models
admin.site.register(cliente)
admin.site.register(producto)
```

And from models.py,

```
from django.db import models

class cliente(models.Model):
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apellidos    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class producto(models.Model):
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I am using MySQL and I am not changing databases. `runserver` did work and I am able to access localhost:8000/admin. There I have a new category called "ventas" which have the "cliente" and the "producto" subcategory. I can access "producto" but "cliente" gives me the DataBase error.

What seems to be wrong? I suspect it has to do with my models.py file but I just don't know why.

Comment: I suspect you changed your schema before? Just an idea. Why don't you load an sqlite database right now, run syncdb and see if it works. If so, the schema in the current database might be out of sync and syncdb didn't handle it. syncdb doesn't handle changed schema for already created database. If my suspect is correct, try South to migrate. Change db in settings.py to a new sqlite db even if you were using postgresql or mysql already. just for testing right now.

Comment: @CppLearner Yes, `syncdb` still works.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page. You are saying after pointing settings.py to a new sqlite3 db, you are able to go into admin?

Comment: let's clarify this.  This error usually suggests you have an outdated table schema. Ask yourself whether you have changed the models.py recently. If so, go to seetings.py, change the database to sqlite3. This does not erase mysql database. You just disconnect django from it for a few minutes. Run syncdb and then runserver, go to admin and see if you have any error. If you still don't want to do the above, that's fine, go to MySQL, check your `cliente` table, and see if you can find `apellido` attribute. I want to rule out one possible cause :p

Comment: I can't even run it when I replace it with sqlite3 because i don't have it installed.

Comment: Verify my claim: go to MySQL, check your cliente table, and see if you can find apellido attribute.

Comment: Yes. It's exactly like I have above.

Answer (score -1):

Your model.py and code are out of sync.

## command

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

### what is does

Goes through the models and if a table **does not** exist for that model, create the table and the matching fields. If a table **does** exists, it does nothing to the table. So if you have added a field then "syncdb", though it sounds like it would, would not create those fields in the database that have been added since the last syncdb.

If you want to sync up your model and your code you have to drop the tables so syncdb will create them. You can use:

```
$ python manage.py flush
```

to "return the database to the state it was in immediately after syncdb was executed." 
source. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush

Comment: You don't want to drop the tables. Don't even do this. You have to get in the habit of doing migration. How are you going to migrate when you are working with a production code and a production environment with live data?

Comment: Great point. If you want to be a pro consider investing and learning south or evolution. This will work just fine though if you want to fix the error and keep coding.

Comment: Yes. That's true, however, he doesn't even understand why it didn't work. He's using MySQL which I think is far better than using sqlite3 within development mode. If he were using sqlite3 we would just say "screw it, delete it." You should suggest him the right practice, but warn him the quick workaround during development mode. :p

Comment: Also, having a setup that includes fixtures and running flush is a fine development practice.